# Connecting to a remote database server at run time

Tags: c#

I designing a application to connect to a remote database. my problem is how to achieve that and make the connection save and permanent. So that the user will not have to go through the process of re-connecting to the database server before they can use the application.

Comment: You should just be able to build your connection string as you desire, and pass that to the constructor for the database connection.

Comment: Do you mean a connection that persists beyond application sessions?  You're talking about saving user credentials?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of application you're creating.  But you can add a key to the config file at runtime and recall it next time the application is run.

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings["connectionString"].Value = "<connectionstring>";     
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```